# AFNetworking Request Time Out but still completed Request

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, file-upload, afnetworking

I'm uploading many files to my server via AFNetworking, either many small files or a couple of large files, but total never uploading more than 250MB of file(s) at once. In order to allow the upload to continue when I exit my app or close my iPhone I say:

```
    [operation setShouldExecuteAsBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"Request time out");
    }];
```

My problem is my upload may take around 10-20min to complete, even though all my files have uploaded, when it finishes I get the "Request time out" message. Any one know what exactly is happening and what I should do to work around this?

```
NSMutableURLRequest *apiRequest =
[self multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST"
                                path:kAPIPath
                          parameters:params
           constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
               //attach file if needed
               if (uploadFile) {
                   [formData appendPartWithStreamingURL:uploadFile
                                               name:@"file"
                                           //fileName:[params objectForKey:@"title"] //Change to test.mp4 or .m4v I'm not sure
                                           mimeType:@"video/quicktime"]; //Change to video/quicktime
               }
           }];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first block of code you posted registers a background task expiration handler, which will be called no matter if your requests have finished or not.

You should check in that block if a request has not finished yet, so you can retry later, for example.